# How can I implement 4 Round Rect Buttons which behave like tabbars items?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

i am trying to create one application that have navigation bar on top of view and just below of navigation bar i want to add 4 buttons that's look like tabbar, i am not using tabbar bar due Apple CONDITIONS.because apple recommend tabbar only on bottom of view. i want to use it on top(just below of navigation bar). so i am using 4 custom buttons for it. i am using the navigation controller for push-pop the views, that have created for according to buttons pressed. could you please explain how to implement like a tabbar. how to buttons will be work like tabbar items.

Comment: add more information in your question and explain what you are trying to implement. Better add some code if you have tried anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check with complete code. which acts like tabbar controller.

```
localViewControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

AllRumsController *allRumsScreen=[[AllRumsController alloc]init];
RumRecipesController *rumRecipesScreen =[[RumRecipesController alloc] init];
PartyPlannerClass *aPartyPlannerScreen =[[PartyPlannerClass alloc] init];
BarTendingClass *aBarTendingScreen =[[BarTendingClass alloc] init];
MoreControllersClass *moreControllerScreen =[[MoreControllersClass alloc] init];

controllersArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:allRumsScreen,rumRecipesScreen,aPartyPlannerScreen,aBarTendingScreen,moreControllerScreen,nil];

for(int i=0;i<[controllersArray count];i++)
{
UINavigationController *localNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:[controllersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
localNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    if(!i)
        [localNavigationController setTitle:@"All Rums"];
    else if(i ==1)
        [localNavigationController setTitle:@"Recipes"];
    else if(i ==2)
        [localNavigationController setTitle:@"PartyPlanner"];
    else if(i ==3)
        [localNavigationController setTitle:@"BarTending"];
    else 
        [localNavigationController setTitle:@"More"];
       localNavigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
       [localViewControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

     [localNavigationController release];
 }
[allRumsScreen release];
[rumRecipesScreen release];
[aPartyPlannerScreen release];
[aBarTendingScreen release];
[moreControllerScreen release];

if(contentView == nil)
{
    contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,MAX_WIDTH, 431)];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
if(bottomView == nil)
{   
    bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,431,MAX_WIDTH, 49)];
    bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}

allButtonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

for(int i=0;i<[localViewControllersArray count];i++)
{
    UIButton *aButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    aButton.frame=CGRectMake(i*64,0,64,49);
    [aButton setTag:i];
    if(!i)
    {
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ourrums_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ourrums_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ourrums_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }
    else if(i ==1)
    {
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Recipies_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Recipies_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Recipies_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

    }else if(i ==2)
    {
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myevents_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myevents_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myevents_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

    }else if(i ==3)
    {
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bartending_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bartending_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bartending_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

    }else 
    {
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [aButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_n.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }
    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showViewOfButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [allButtonsArray addObject:aButton];
    [bottomView addSubview:aButton];
}

[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:contentView];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:bottomView];

[bottomView setHidden:YES];
[contentView setHidden:YES];


[self showViewOfButton:[allButtonsArray objectAtIndex:0]];





-(void)showViewOfButton:(id)sender
    {
if(start == YES)
{
    start = NO;
    [repeat setTag:[sender tag]];
}
else if([repeat tag] == [sender tag])
{
    return;
}
else
{
    [repeat setTag:[sender tag]];
}

if(previous!=nil)
{
    [previous setImage:[previous imageForState:UIControlStateDisabled] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


if( [[contentView subviews] count] )
{
    if([[RumsDataHolder sharedHolder] mailController])
    {
        [[[[RumsDataHolder sharedHolder] mailController] retain] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
    [[[contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}

if( ((UIView *)sender).tag == 0)
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ourrums_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [contentView addSubview:[[localViewControllersArray objectAtIndex:0] view]];
}
else if( ((UIView *)sender).tag == 1)
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Recipies_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [contentView addSubview:[[localViewControllersArray objectAtIndex:1] view]];
}
else if(((UIView *)sender).tag == 2)
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myevents_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [contentView addSubview:[[localViewControllersArray objectAtIndex:2] view]];
}
else if( ((UIView *)sender).tag == 3)
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bartending_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [contentView addSubview:[[localViewControllersArray objectAtIndex:3] view]];
}
else if(((UIView *)sender).tag == 4)
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_a.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [contentView addSubview:[[localViewControllersArray objectAtIndex:4] view]];
}
else
    ;
previous=sender;
}
```

Comment: thanks Madhu....could you share the complete project source for help.or any reference link for the same. i unable to implement it in my application.

Comment: Its simple one. Ask me where your struck in. i will help out. Its on going project of mine and unable to post it. sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do like bellow points.

- put 4 Round Rect Button at bottom of Xib.
- create 4 class for Each button and joit proparly IBAction With Buttons.
  now you can push and pop without Animation like:-

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjYourViewcontroler animated:NO];`

and pop it like:-

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of using `UIbuttons` or invoking the whole `UITabbarController` why not use `UITabbar` and `tabbar items` Here's the code..This should get you going:)

```
 UITabBar *tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(your frame)];   
  NSMutableArray  *tabBarItemsArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"artist" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"artist-tab.png"] tag:1];//assigning the title name and image
[tabBarItem1 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0/255.0  green:60.0/255.0 blue:109.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//set the color when the tabbar appears

[tabBarItem1 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];//sets the color when the tabbar is selected

 UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Facebook" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music-tab.png"] tag:2];

[tabBarItem2 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor colorWithRed:48.0/255.0  green:60.0/255.0 blue:109.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[tabBarItem2 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        [tabBarItemsArray addObject:tabBarItem1];
        [tabBarItemsArray addObject:tabBarItem2];
        tabBar.items = tabBarItemsArray;
        tabBar.delegate = self;

     [self.view addSubview:tabBar];
```

Make sure you add the delegate UITabBarDelegate in your header file to implement this method

```
  - (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
        NSLog(@"Tabbar selected itm %d",item.tag); 
   // here you can call your view based on tab click you can try using switch statements here based on item.tag
       }
```

Hope this answers your question and helps:)

Also,we can customize the UITabbar with an image...do let me know..i will post the code in here if you want.

Answer (score 0):

To behave the same like tabbar controller, follow the same steps to create tabbar controller programmatically,

Create Tabbar

> create instance for each UIViewController you want to push on click of UIButton, add it as rootviewcontroller for `UINavigationController` and all objects of it into `NSArray` and set that array to `_tabBarController.viewControllers`, then add _tabBarController.view to `self.window`

Create Custom View

> next now create a `UIView` with the same frame as for the position of _tabBarController in a view, add `UIButton`s you want to show on _tabBarController, button can be custom for any background images or to match your require UI look, add all those buttons as subview to `UIView` and finally that view object to `self.window` subview. Up to this, you'll have look of custom tabbar with all buttons you want, now make behave it like tabbar.

Don't forget to add an action to each button you've added, the action implementation something like,

```
- (void)select_tab:(UIButton *)sender
{
   _tabBarController.selectedIndex = sender.tag;
   //_tabBarController is object of UITabBarController
}
```

Remember, its also needed that each button should be with some tag set, these tags will be work as index for the current tabbar index, so give the tag in order you've add the viewcontrollers into array, button tag should start with 0 (zero) base index up to maximum viewcontrollers you've.

That's it, hope this helps!